# Break long source lines, but only on comma

Tags: php, coding-style, sed, awk, indentation

Background:  I use PHPStylist to indent PHP code, which is generally working out fine. But, when it find function calls with many arguments, it puts all these arguments on one single line. So for instance a `bind_param()` call can easily be 300 characters wide.

This does not play well with our coding style guide, which dictates a maximum line length of 180 characters.

Our indent script already has a sed command to clean off trailing whitespace left by PHPStylist, so I was thinking, can sed also break too long lines, but only on a comma?

Example input:

```
function xyz()
{
    somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1);
}
```

Example output:

```
function xyz()
{
    somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1,
$somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1, $somevariable1);
}
```

<sup>(Bonus points if the script could also indent the next line prettily, but I think that would be very hard to do in sed.  A solution in awk, perl, python or other common tool would be very appreciated too.)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk script will split your lines at the last comma before the max line length, which you can set as a run-time argument if you like. It indents the split-off lines by 4 spaces more than the original lines:

```
$ cat file
function xyz()
{
    somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable2, $somevariable3, $somevariable4, $somevariable5, $somevariable6, $somevariable7, $somevariable8, $somevariable9);

        somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable2, $somevariable3, $somevariable4, $somevariable5, $somevariable6, $somevariable7, $somevariable8, $somevariable9);
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
function xyz()
{
    somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable2, $somevariable3,
        $somevariable4, $somevariable5, $somevariable6,
        $somevariable7, $somevariable8,
        $somevariable9);

        somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable2, $somevariable3,
                $somevariable4, $somevariable5, $somevariable6,
                $somevariable7, $somevariable8,
                $somevariable9);
}
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ maxLength = (maxLength ? maxLength : 66) }

(length($0) > maxLength) && /,/ {
    indent = $0
    sub(/[^[:space:]].*/,"",indent)

    tail = $0
    while (tail ~ /[^[:space:]]/) {
        head = substr(tail,1,maxLength)
        sub(/,[^,]+$/,",",head)
        tail = substr(tail,length(head)+1)
        sub(/^[[:space:]]*/,indent"    ",tail)
        print head
    }
    next
}
1

$ awk -v maxLength=100 -f tst.awk file
function xyz()
{
    somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable2, $somevariable3, $somevariable4, $somevariable5,
        $somevariable6, $somevariable7, $somevariable8,
        $somevariable9);

        somecall($somevariable1, $somevariable2, $somevariable3, $somevariable4, $somevariable5,
                $somevariable6, $somevariable7, $somevariable8,
                $somevariable9);
}

$ awk -v maxLength=30 -f tst.awk file
function xyz()
{
    somecall($somevariable1,
        $somevariable2,
        $somevariable3,
        $somevariable4,
        $somevariable5,
        $somevariable6,
        $somevariable7,
        $somevariable8,
        $somevariable9);

        somecall($somevariable1,
                $somevariable2,
                $somevariable3,
                $somevariable4,
                $somevariable5,
                $somevariable6,
                $somevariable7,
                $somevariable8,
                $somevariable9);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a first suggestion, something like this?

```
sed 's/.\{70\}[^,]*,/&\
/g' file
```

---edit---

For indenting, you could try:

```
sed -e 's/\(.\{70\}[^,]*,\)[[:blank:]]*/\1\
/g; tend' -e n  -e :end -e 's/\(^[[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\n\)/\1\2\1/ ' file
```

Comment: The lower one does not indent correctly if the line needs to broken into more than one, but nevertheless, awesome answer! I think I will use the top one. Thanks again!